# does google talk use udp or tcp packets?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, google-talk

is it possible to determine whether google talk uses tcp or udp packets for transmission.
i know it uses the xmpp protocol at the application layer, but does it run over tcp or udp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can infer what the answer is: Google Talk works in a browser *without* requiring a plugin. The only protocol supported through the communication mechanism XMLHttpRequest is TCP/HTTP.

If you are interested in XMPP, have a look [here](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html).

> ...wherein a client utilizing XMPP
>   accesses a server over a [TCP]
>   connection, and servers also
>   communicate with each other over TCP
>   connections.

Comment: That's just the Google Talk web client, not the protocol.

Comment: ... but of course... that was the question, wasn't it? The question can't be about XMPP because one can "google" for an answer, right ;-)

Answer (score 10):

You can answer this yourself by using a packet sniffer to watch the traffic. This will be *much* more instructive than having us tell you the answer.