# how to listen continuosly for instream or outstrem in sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, chat

I am making a chat application in android using TCP and has immplemented Sockets. Which is working but in case of receiving or sending only the first msg is considered.
eg. client:hi
server:hi
server:hows u?

so in this case **hows u?** is not accessible at client / server side. In both cases instream is closed after receiving once. Can any One suggest what could be the issues or how i can solve them???

Comment: are you using any API to communicate over socket?

Comment: its java.net API in android app

Comment: Use smack api to communicate. It's easy to use.

Comment: can it be used to make tcp connections??

Comment: no smack is for XMPP. If you want to use TCP then read this: http://pguides.net/java/tcp-client-server-chat it might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not listening for server continuously, then there might be a problem with your code. Post your code.

Check if this fits your requirement.
[Android chat functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950017/android-chat-functionality)

Comment: Is there any way, I want to do this with TCP?

Comment: I believe that XMPP (at application layer) works on top of TCP . Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629582/does-google-talk-use-udp-or-tcp-packets